# Notepad++ cannot find filepath

Tags: python, notepad++

I'm trying to run a Hello World program in Python I wrote in Notepad++ using the NppExec plugin, but instead of printing, I'm getting

```
python C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Test.py
CreateProcess() failed with error code 2:
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The argument I'm giving NppExec is

```
python C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Test.py
```

which is the filepath that NP++ gives me when I copy the full filepath to the clipboard.

Is there some configuration of NP++ that I have to set to get this to work?

Comment: Can you give full path to python like `c:\foo\python.exe` ?

Comment: If you have `.py` files associated with your Python installation, just do `C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Test.py`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried what you are attempting to do, and this is how I solved it:

Instead of passing the argument you gave, I passed this one:

```
C:\Python32\python.exe C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Test.py for python 3+
C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Test.py for python 2
```

Generally, in order for it to work, you have to define where you have installed the python executable.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can use the following as an argument to NppExec for any currently opened Python script in Notepad++:

```
    [Your Python install folder here]\python.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

Note that "FULL_CURRENT_PATH" is a Notepad++ internal variable, not a placeholder for your file's actual path and filename, so the above argument should work without edits regardless of your current script's filename.

Further references for using NppExec with other source code: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Compiling_Source_Code

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative method to running python programs in notepad++, which I recommend after being unable to find a suitable plugin.

create a batch file called pythonXX.bat ( where XX is the current version of python you're using ) and save it along side your python.exe in C:\PythonXX\

and insert this text into that batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
C:\PythonXX\python.exe "%1"
PAUSE
@ECHO ON
```

Then inside notepad++ create a run command:

C:\PythonXX\pythonXX.bat "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"

Then click save run and assign it to a keyboard short-cut, good to go :)

Comment: I find your answer better formatted now, but still he is trying to use nppexec plugin, and he is asking for the correct argument for it.